# Using Projections in Spring Data JPA field error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I new member of java Spring, today I try to query with `CrudRepository` of JPA. I using `Projections`.

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepositoty extends CrudRepository<tbl_user, Integer> {
// search by username
@Query(value = "select (select l.state from tbl_request_love l where l.senderid = u.userid) as state, u.userid as userid,u.username as username,u.nickname as nickname,u.avatar as avatar"
        + " from tbl_user u"
        + " where u.username LIKE CONCAT('%',:username,'%') and u.coupleid is null" , nativeQuery = true)
List<tbl_user_search> findByUsernameEndWith(@Param("username") String username);
}
```

My interface:

```
public interface tbl_user_search {
int getUserid();
String getUsername();
String getNickname();
String getAvatar();
String getState();
}
```

When I test I get this error:

> Could not write JSON: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [int] for value 'hihi';
>   nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"hihi\";
>   nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [int] for value 'hihi';
>   nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"hihi\"
>
> (through reference chain:
>   skay.model.api_searchuser[\"result\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87[\"userid\"])`

If I change type `getUserid();` in my interface to `String` this error done and have a new json.

```
{
    "state": "Hi",
    "username": "https://forumhumgeduvn.000webhostapp.com/5skay/man.png",
    "userid": "Hi Hi",
    "avatar": "Pending",
    "nickname": "3"
}
```

but the json does not returns fields in order. I think this is problem my error. But I don't know fix it.You can share any solve for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `LIKE` like this:

```
" where u.username LIKE %:username% and u.coupleid is null"
```

or :

```
" where u.username LIKE %?1% and u.coupleid is null"
```

Read this [Using advanced LIKE expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_using_advanced_code_like_code_expressions)

Comment: I try it an i have a new bug : Unknown column 'u.userid' in 'field list'. You can help me ?

Comment: @phạmtuấn can you try using this query instead `SELECT l.state AS state,
       u.userid AS userid,
       u.username AS username,
       u.nickname AS nickname,
       u.avatar AS avatar
FROM tbl_user u, tbl_request_love l
WHERE 
l.senderid = u.userid 
AND u.username LIKE %?1%
AND u.coupleid IS NULL`